# How can I handle this firestore security rules error?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, firebase-security

Once I have changed the security rules it keeps giving me this error on whatever the rules are:[image]

My security rules now:
[image: My security rules now:]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete google-services.json and reinstall it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).